# Javascript regexp capture matches delimited by character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```
classifier1:11:some text1##classifier2:fdglfgfg##classifier3:fgdfgfdg##classifier4
```

I am trying to capture terms like classifier1:11, classifier2:, classifier3 and classifier4

So these classifiers can be followed by a single semicolon or not.

So far I came up with

```
/([^#]*)(?::(?!:))/g
```

But that does not seem to capture classifier4, not sure what I am missing here

Comment: Try [`([^#]+)(?::(?!:)|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/oL6kQ0/2). Why did you use the lookahead? It looks like you also can use `([^#]+)(?::|$)`

Comment: It's because `classifier4` does not have a colon (`:`) immediately after it

Comment: Do you mean there can be cases like `classifier1::11::xxxx`? What is the expected result for `classifier1::11::some text1##classifier2`?

Comment: Maybe try [`(\w+(?::+\w+)*\d)[^#]*`](https://regex101.com/r/oL6kQ0/3)?

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution works, maybe you could add it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Which one? `(\w+(?::+\w+)*\d)[^#]*`? The thing is, your specs are not clear, I need to know how to answer, what to explain. When you say *classifier is not a literal string, it could be anything*, it is ok, it means we should be using `[^#]*`, but what about the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a classifier in your case consists of any word chars that may have single `:` in between and ends with a digit.

Thus, you may use

```
/(\w+(?::+\w+)*\d)[^#]*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL6kQ0/4)

**Explanation**:

- `(\w+(?::+\w+)*\d)` - Group 1 capturing

  - `\w+` - 1 or more `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (word) chars
  - `(?::+\w+)*` - zero or more sequences of 1+ `:`s and then 1+ word chars
  - `\d` - a digit should be at the end of this group
- `[^#]*` - zero or more characters other than the delimiter `#`.

JS:

```js
var re = /(\w+(?::+\w+)*\d)[^#\n]*/g; 
var str = 'classifier4##classifier1:11:some text1##classifier2:fdglfgfg##classifier3:fgdfgfdg\nclassifier1:11:some text1##classifier4##classifier2:fdglfgfg##classifier3:fgdfgfdg##classifier4';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Basing on your pattern you can use a regex like this:

```
([^#]*)(?::|$)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC1oQ7/1)**

Comment: this works for this pattern but what if classifier4 appeared in between or at the start of the string ?? like  `classifier4##classifier1:11:some text1##classifier2:fdglfgfg##classifier3:fgdfgfdg` or `classifier1:11:some text1##classifier4##classifier2:fdglfgfg##classifier3:fgdfgfdg`

Comment: @AnandSunderraman, is classifier a literal string. Could you use `(classifier\d+:?\d*)`?. How do you differentiate between `text1` and `classifier1`?

Comment: No classifier is not a literal string, it could be anything

Comment: @AnandSunderraman so, what's the pattern different between `text1` and `classifier1` ?